# How to track your theme usage on the internet?

Tags: themes

themers and moders.

Often I get inspiration for my theme (Tiny Forge) from the real websites that are using it. Unfortunately it is not an easy task to find on google who's using your theme.

I thought about using meta generator, but that's reserved for WordPress. Then I thought to put in a comment with theme name and perhaps version, but Google doesn't index comments... then the last remedy is to insert hidden text with display: none; but I'm afraid this can have an impact on user's website google rank?

What is your experience to find your theme implementation on the web? Are you using any "fingerprinting" or "watermarking" methods?

Comment: No, I'm not. Because I would consider doing so to be a violation of the end user's right to use my Theme for any purpose, without being required to disclose that use to me as the developer. That is a fundamental right and principle of free software philosophy, implicitly, though not explicitly, protected under the GPL under which I distribute my Theme.

Comment: Chip, thanks for your input. I checked your blog and found this line: `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.6-RC1-24704"/>`. Isn't that disclosure that you're using WP and exact version? And of course you can find this line with google. I'm not sure why the rule that should be applied to GPL theme, should not be applied to WP itself?

If I would do something like this, I would add this as an option (enabled by default), that user can easily comment out.

Comment: `"should not be applied to WP itself"` No. Build your own WP if you want to sniff your users' whereabouts. Or ask them politely *"hey, click this link where I can track you"*.

Comment: What the end user chooses to do and what you as a developer force upon that user are two different things. You could leave a commented line in your source and kindly ask your users to uncomment if they would like to participate in feedback. But, forcing them into something is a plain invasion of their privacy. Your `enabled by default` option, goes against this.

Comment: I got another idea. Perhaps I will use the script by Konstantin Kovshenin that he's using to encourage people to vote for the theme Expound, but change it to gear users to WP forum theme, where they can showcase their site.

Comment: You will need to make this opt in, if you add something that phones home for marketing purpose you may very well be running foul of data protection laws in a number of countries

Answer (score 4):

> You don't.

But there are 3 ways you can if you wanted to, they can all be circumvented because of open source, thankfully.

**Parse source or something**
Crawl the web and parse the source or an url for a custom comment/id/whatever.
*Chance of failure: Really High* - unless you're Google

**Create an API**
Call home with an API
*Chance of failure: High* - you have better things to do

**Custom Response Header**
Create a custom response header
*Chance of failure: Medium* - this is the only realistic way you can crawl the web and it's easy to implement (and disable) , it's also annoying unless so you better have a good reason.

Case in point ..

[image]

.... don't pollute the internet with custom headers...

You're suggestion to hide it via CSS would incur the wrath of satan himself. Seriously though don't do that, ever.

ps . There is a 4th option but I'm certainly not telling you since your motives are unclear.

Comment: Thank you, Wyck, for the comment. Special CSS ID or Class sounds like a harmless option. It could be something like tiny-forge-header. If there will be no other suggestions, will mark as an answer ;)

Comment: How on earth are you going to crawl CSS for millions of sites? Put it in the source as a visible comment so that people browsing the site might look at the source and see it, that is really your only option, be upfront, don't hide shit.

Comment: Motives are to see how people implemented your work. Personally it gives me ideas and gives me positive feedback that something I created was actually usefull. And of course, keep that 4th option in secret :D

Comment: Overall you should not disclose that option in any case, because it can be used by any other "bad" reader who would find your solution in the future. Better keep it secret, keep it safe!

Comment: If you do that you are a detriment to open source, stop using WordPress and go find something else.

Comment: If you are such big fighter for the privacy, could you please help WP community to solve this problem: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16778

I'm a second class citizen in Open Source community, I cannot do some things, but not all are created equal... WP can do this, because they just CAN.

Comment: You can disable this using a filter.

Comment: Sure, tell this to millions of people that don't even know about the fact that they are tracked, and doesn't know what "filter" means.

Comment: Don't be so dramatic, WordPress has to know when a new version is available, the same goes for plugins, how else do you think updates work? It also gathers what version of PHP/MYSQL is used because it maintains backwards compatibility and they have a [privacy policy](http://wordpress.org/about/privacy/) Comparing that to hiding your credentials via CSS is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

So after some time here are my findings. These are the ways I would discover websites that are using my themes:

1. http://www.wpbyexample.com there are also other similar sites.
2. Free support - you provide free support and users will come to ask questions, in many cases they want to show their sites, so you can evaluate problems.
3. Link to my website in the footer. In many cases users would use it to visit my site that has tutorials related to theme. Yost Google Analytics plugin has dashboard in Admin area that makes it very easy to see from what sites people come to visit your website.

BTW users @ Advanced WordPress group on FaceBook were not so zealous about this issue as some commenters above...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old but also a harmless question, why shouldn't he be allowed to track his own theme usage? It might be best though to mention this in your terms of service for downloading the theme that you will be tracking its usage.

Anyway the short answer is to use a tracking beacon. Same thing people use to track open emails. Basically you insert a transparent 1x1 pixel image somewhere in your theme. Make sure the tracker beacon is hosted by you and it has a unique identifier name per each theme or version of the theme. Then each time it's loaded from your server you get to not only see where it's being used but also how often it's being used!